# Combining two variables ggplot: geom_pointrange and geom_point

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, median, confidence-interval

I am trying to combine in one graph two variables,
  one as a geom_pointrange [cause I need min and max representation (confidence interval 2.5% and 97.5% and its median (50%)]

other variable is a geom_point, made by median of other calculus.

I found ggplot make these representations, but I have not gotten it together, by:

```
#inputs
x <- seq(1:10)
n <- length(x)
yone <- 2 * runif(n)
ytwo <- runif(n)
ythree <- ytwo * 0.2
yfour <- ytwo * 2

df <- data.frame(x, yone, ytwo, ythree, yfour); df


library (ggplot2)

#yone and ytwo must be points
#ythree and yfour are min and max confidence interval (vertical line)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y = value, color = variable)) + 
geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = ythree, ymax = yfour)) + 
geom_point(aes(y = yone, col = "yone")) +
geom_point(aes(y = ytwo, col = "ytwo")) +
geom_line(aes(y = yfour))
```

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: What should the result look like?  Can you point us to a similar graphic?  Also, right now your example doesn't run, as the dataset you give doesn't contain `value` or `variable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution to get the type of plot you seem to be aiming for. I've used the `reshape2` package to change your data into long form. There are many options for reshaping, including `tidyr` (gather), base R (reshape), and `data.table` (melt). For the `yone` rows in the melted data.frame, I've set the confidence intervals to `NA` since you didn't compute those. Finally, I've used `geom_linerange` together with `geom_point` instead of `geom_pointrange`, in order to handle the `NA` values gracefully.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

# Reshape data to long form.
mdat <- melt(df, id.vars=c("x", "ythree", "yfour"))

# Set confidence intervals to NA for yone values,
# values for which you didn't compute CIs.
mdat[mdat$variable == "yone", c("ythree", "yfour")] <- NA

p = ggplot(data=mdat, aes(x=x, y=value, colour=variable, ymin=ythree, ymax=yfour)) + 
    geom_linerange() + 
    geom_point(size=3) +
    geom_line(aes(y=yfour), linetype="dotted")

ggsave ("plot.png", p, height=4, width=6, dpi=150)
```

[image]